# Sphinx 1.3.3 Does not create PDF file on Windows 7

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-sphinx

I have successfully created HTML documentation using Sphinx.
I would now like to create a PDF.
I run the following on the command line (as per manual).

```
make latexpdf
```

I get the output below with no errors reported.

```
Running Sphinx v1.3.3
making output directory...
loading pickled environment... done
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
building [latex]: all documents
updating environment: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 removed
looking for now-outdated files... none found
processing MOBVRMDataTransferTool.tex... index overview sourcecodecontrol dependencies configuration references
resolving references...
writing... done
copying images... _static/VDT_Flow_Current_Overall.png
copying TeX support files...
done
build succeeded.
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Build finished; the PDF files are in _build/latex.
```

There is no PDF file in the directory `_build/latex`.

```
C:\virtual_env\m_vdt\m_vdt\docs\_build\latex>dir
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is 8A04-040B

 Directory of C:\virtual_env\m_vdt\m_vdt\docs\_build\latex

15/12/2015  09:04 AM    <DIR>          .
15/12/2015  09:04 AM    <DIR>          ..
15/12/2015  09:01 AM            18,775 fncychap.sty
15/12/2015  09:01 AM             2,057 Makefile
15/12/2015  09:04 AM            21,650 MOBVRMDataTransferTool.tex
15/12/2015  09:01 AM               220 python.ist
15/12/2015  09:01 AM            16,124 sphinx.sty
15/12/2015  09:01 AM             2,699 sphinxhowto.cls
15/12/2015  09:01 AM             4,101 sphinxmanual.cls
15/12/2015  09:01 AM            13,844 tabulary.sty
10/02/2015  02:39 PM            64,116 VDT_Flow_Current_Overall.png
                9 File(s)        143,586 bytes
                2 Dir(s)  343,139,319,808 bytes free
```

Any idea where to start looking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must install a make program (optional), e.g. [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/),  and a LaTeX distribution such as [MiKTeX](http://miktex.org/about) in order to generate the pdf file.

If you don't have `make` installed, you can generate the pdf file by

```
make latex
cd _build/latex
latexmk -pdf *.tex
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I had to install a perl interpreter as well to get it to work. Unfortunately the resulting PDF was not acceptable. It failed to put the module documentation together, and there were a bunch of blank pages . I guess I will have to resort to copy and pasting into Word.

Comment: The blank pages are intentional since the default setting is for double sided printing. I have written a post about it (and many other possible problems)     https://www.topbug.net/blog/2015/12/11/a-collection-of-issues-about-the-latex-output-in-sphinx-and-the-solutions/